# JSONP post request

Tags: html, css, json, api

I'd like to use [ProCSSor API](http://procssor.com/apidoc.pdf) ([example query](http://procssor.com/api?source=uri&css=http://graphics8.nytimes.com/css/0.1/screen/build/homepage/styles.css&indent_rules=1&indent_size=default)) but only if the query will happen as JSONP POST, to assure it will work in the front-end, but I'm not sure how.

I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it looks like the procssor api only responds with json. It doesn't give the option to return with jsonp.

The example query link returns this:

```
{"css":"body\n{\n    margin: 0;\n  ... lots more stuff ... }
```

For JSONP, you'd need it to return something like this:

```
myFunction({"css":"body\n{\n    margin: 0;\n  ... lots more stuff ... })
```

Then, in your code, you could define `myFunction()` to do whatever you need to do with the json returned.

Perhaps you could email the folks at http://procssor.com and ask them to provide an api param like "jsonp". If they added that parameter, then you could call the api like this:

```
http://procssor.com/api?source=uri&css=<url_to_css>&indent_rules=1&indent_size=default&jsonp=myFunction
```